# how to create this second hidden table

Tags: html, css

hidden element in HTML

I would like to get the same result that this example please.

When the user clicks on `783`

[image]

a second HTML table appears

[image]

Here is my table and when I click on `32` or another value in grey. I would like to display a HTML table with 2 columns.

[image]

```html
<table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%; text-align: center;">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 14%; background-color: #dee2e657; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 10%;">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%;">LABEL </th>
         <th scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">LABEL </th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">10</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">30</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">58</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">11</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">17</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 12%; background-color: #dee2e657;">32</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">44</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">20</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">10</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">11</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 4%; ">20</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">40</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">18</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">31</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">27</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 12%; background-color: #dee2e657;">47</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10%; ">25</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 5%; ">21</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">90</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 9%; ">51</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I would use javascript to add click event handlers to those table cells. Those handlers can manipulate the DOM so that you can create your table or show/hide and position it with CSS properties.

Comment: I would recommend checking out datatables.net. A lot of functionality and a helpful community